# Update Chart using ChartJS - VueJS

Tags: javascript, charts, vue.js

so I'm having some problems when trying to update a chart using VueJS and ChartJS. I'm currently running a ajax request (using axios) and trying to draw a chart from the data returned.

The problem is when trying to draw the chart I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined at eval (App.vue?26cd:520)`. I don't really know why this is happening, I've read some other posts but still can't seem to get it working. This is the code I'm using:

```
<template>
  <button @click="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
  <canvas ref="myChart"></canvas>
</template>
-----------------------------------------------------------

methods: {
  myFunction () {
    var self = this

    axios.post('http://localhost/link/to/file.php', {
      // Post params here
    }).then(response => {
      var ctxChart = self.$refs.myChart.getContext('2d')

      var myChart = new Chart(ctxChart, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
          labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4'],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Label here',
            data: [response.data['data1'], response.data['data2'], response.data['data3'], response.data['data4']],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
        }
      })

    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Put a breakpoint and make sure that `myChart` is a defined `$ref`.

Comment: If this is all the code, then problematic line is `var ctxChart = self.$refs.myChart.getContext('2d')`. When do you call myFunction? Make sure to call if after mounted

Comment: @FrEaKmAn I call it when the button is clicked `@click="myFunction()"`.

Comment: @zero298 Hmm whenever I do a `console.log(self.$refs)` I can see my chart reference there. But when I do a `console.log(self.$refs.myChart)` I get `Undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem. I solved it by wrapping everything with `nextTick`

```
self.$nextTick(() => {
    var ctxChart = self.$refs.myChart.getContext('2d')
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. Didn't know about `nextTick()`.